# disable click until hover animation complete

Tags: jquery, click, hover, jquery-animate

```
$('#div1, #div2').click(function(){

//Code to execute onclick


    });


$('#div1, #div2').hover(function(){

    $(this).animate({
        'filter':'alpha(opacity=100)',
        '-moz-opacity':'1',
        '-khtml-opacity':'1',
        'opacity': '1'},
        250,
        function(){
    $(this).animate({
            'filter':'alpha(opacity=75)',
            '-moz-opacity':'0.75',
            '-khtml-opacity':'0.75',
            'opacity': '0.75'},
            500)
        });
    });
```

I have two divs that hav a click event and a hover event, and both have animations.  How can i make it so that when a user hovers on either div: -

```
- the click event doesnt work until the hover animation is complete
- and then the hover animation doesnt work until the click animation is complete
```

At the moment, if a user clicks div1 and then hovers on div2 before the click is complete it has an undesirable effect, eg flashing and things disappearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$('#div1, #div2').click(function(){

if(('#div1:animated, #div2:animated').length == 0)
{
//Code to execute onclick

}
});
```

a working demo
http://jsfiddle.net/RSZYd/

Answer (score 0):

You can call the click event in the hover event like this:

```
$('#div1, #div2').hover(function(){
    $(this).unbind('click'); //unbind first
    $(this).animate({
        'filter':'alpha(opacity=100)',
        '-moz-opacity':'1',
        '-khtml-opacity':'1',
        'opacity': '1'},
        250,
        function(){
    $(this).animate({
            'filter':'alpha(opacity=75)',
            '-moz-opacity':'0.75',
            '-khtml-opacity':'0.75',
            'opacity': '0.75'},
            500,
            function(){
              $(this).click(function(){
                 //Code to execute onclick
              });
            })
        });         
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work-out for your requirement :

```
function fxhover($this)
{
    $this.unbind('click');
    $this.animate({/*somecode*/},100,function() {
        animate({/*somecode*/},100, function(){
            $this.bind('click',function(){fxclick($this);})     
        }
    })
}
function fxclick($this)
{
    $this.unbind('hover');
    $this.animate({/*somecode*/},100,function(){
        $this.hover(function(){
            fxhover($this);
        })
    })
}
$('#div1, #div2').hover(function(){
    fxhover($(this));
})
$('#div1, #div2').click(function(){
    fxclick($(this));
})
```